# Pre-training with eigenfaces

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, face-recognition

I have a lot of training faces (grouped by person) but I've timing constraints.

So is it possible to do a pre-training on each person (with eigenfaces) in order to obtain a some kind of 'mean-face' for each user, and then re-apply the eigenfaces algorithm on those 'mean-faces' for comparing different people?

I am afraid that if I did, the algorithm would have an even lower rate of recognition

Comment: This deserves a +1 just for the term *mean-face* alone :-)

Comment: You might also have to get them to smile or the system will only recognise them when they are angry. More seriously, the question you are asking really is how much information can I throw away vs how successful the facial recognition process will be on a crowd of people. The more you use a "common face" the more likely it is the system will only recognise people within a certain number of standard deviations of the characteristic of that face.